# Page Redirection doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I grabbed a piece of code a login and registration script when i run the index.php from apache it gives this error in the address tab

```
http://localhost/johnlogin/?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login?msg=login
```

and this below error on the browser page

The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

I dig out the code but cant solve the problem here's the code of index.php

```
require_once('load.php');
$logged = $j->checkLogin();

if ( $logged == false ) {
    //Build our redirect
    $url = "http" . ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $redirect = str_replace('index.php', 'login.php', $url);

    //Redirect to the home page
    header("Location: $redirect?msg=login");
    exit;
} else {
    //Grab our authorization cookie array
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['joombologauth'];

    //Set our user and authID variables
    $user = $cookie['user'];
    $authID = $cookie['authID'];

    //Query the database for the selected user
    $table = 'j_users';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_login = '" . $user . "'";
    $results = $jdb->select($sql);

    //Kill the script if the submitted username doesn't exit
    if (!$results) {
        die('Sorry, that username does not exist!');
    }

    //Fetch our results into an associative array
    $results = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results );
```

?>

the load.php basically consists a require_once statement which loads db and a class file here's the class code which id been called by

```
$logged = $j->checkLogin();
```

---------the class.php code-------

```
        function checkLogin() {
        global $jdb;

        //Grab our authorization cookie array
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['joombologauth'];

        //Set our user and authID variables
        $user = $cookie['user'];
        $authID = $cookie['authID'];

        /*
         * If the cookie values are empty, we redirect to login right away;
         * otherwise, we run the login check.
         */
        if ( !empty ( $cookie ) ) {

            //Query the database for the selected user
            $table = 'login';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE uName = '" . $user . "'";
            $results = $jdb->select($sql);

            //Kill the script if the submitted username doesn't exit
            if (!$results) {
                die('Sorry, that username does not exist!');
            }

            //Fetch our results into an associative array
            $results = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results );

            //The registration date of the stored matching user
            $storeg = $results['user_registered'];

            //The hashed password of the stored matching user
            $stopass = $results['user_pass'];

            //Rehash password to see if it matches the value stored in the cookie
            $authnonce = md5('cookie-' . $user . $storeg . AUTH_SALT);
            $stopass = $jdb->hash_password($stopass, $authnonce);

            if ( $stopass == $authID ) {
                $results = true;
            } else {
                $results = false;
            }
        } else {
            //Build our redirect
            $url = "http" . ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "s" : "") . "://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $redirect = str_replace('index.php', 'login.php', $url);

            //Redirect to the home page
            header("Location: $redirect?msg=login");
            exit;
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

all the bug is being happening here

regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your script is recursively redirecting to itself.

The problem is when you first try to access the page, the script determines you as not logged in : `if ( $logged == false )`

and it redirects you to the login.php with params, which are further redirecting it to the same page, hence your script keeps on looping. When your web server (apache) loops it for a certain amount of time it flags the request to be unable to service, hence the error.

Comment: Munjal whats the remedy